# File name is showing in wrong encode after uploading to ftp server

Tags: c#, wpf, ftp

After uploading of file to ftp server, file name is showing ????????. File name contains Cyrillic words. But inside of this file is showing correct. What should be done to show correct file names? My code is here:

```
        FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(filepath);
        string fileName = fileInfo.Name.ToString();
        WebRequest requestFTP = WebRequest.Create(IncomingFtpPath + fileName);

        requestFTP.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ftpusername, ftppassword);
        requestFTP.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
        FileStream fStream = fileInfo.OpenRead();
        int bufferLength = 2048;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferLength];

        Stream uploadStream = requestFTP.GetRequestStream();
        int contentLength = fStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferLength);

        while (contentLength != 0)
        {
            uploadStream.Write(buffer, 0, contentLength);
            contentLength = fStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
        }
        uploadStream.Close();
        fStream.Close();
        requestFTP = null;
```

Comment: Your ftp server does support that type of characters?

Comment: Good question, I am not sure.

Comment: I have checked, yes it does